# Why does keyframe animation repeat more than once?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

```css
.a.b{
    border: 2px solid red;
    animation-name: appear;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
   }

   @keyframes appear{
     from{opacity:0;
         transform:rotateZ(20deg);
           top:100;}
     to{opacity:1;
       top:0;
       transform:rotate(0);}
   }

   @keyframes zoomer{
     from{
       opacity:0.5;
     }
     to{
       opacity:1;
     }
   }

   .a.b:hover{
    animation: zoomer 1s linear 1;
   }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div>
   <h1 class="a b">hello world</h1>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

In the above code snippet, why does the `@keyframes` animation repeat when I use hover? The number of iterations are specified as 1.

My guess is that the class associated with the `<h1>` tag changes when we hover and then again changes when we remove the mouse. But how are we going to fix it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "repeat"? Do you mean that the "appear" animation happens on load, then again once the cursor is moved off the element?

Comment: @FunkyDelPueblo Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation is triggering because the `:hover` pseudoclass overrides`<h1>`'s `animation` property. When the pseudoclass is removed, the `animation` property "changes" again, back to its original value, which triggers the animation.

There are a few ways you could get around this behavior. If you want to have the `<h1>` animate on load, but never again, consider creating a separate class:

```
.a.b.onload {
    animation-name: appear;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Then in Javascript, remove the class after waiting 1 second for the initial animation to finish:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    setTimeout( () => {
        document.querySelector(".a.b").classList.remove("onload")
    }, 1000);
});
```